# Why doesn't my print preview element hide when the print preview is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am wanting the  print-content class to be hidden when print preview closes. Pressing Control P in IE will trigger it or simply go file > print preview. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="print" ">
    .print-content {
        display: none !important;
    }


    @media print {
        .print-content { display: block !important;}

        textarea {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeprint = function () {
        $('.print-content').remove();
        $('textarea').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).val();
            $(this).after('<p class="well print-content">' + text + '</p>');
        });
    }
</script>
```

TextArea MarkUp

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <textarea name="textarea" id="the_textarea">    Some note
            orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt congue cursus. Nunc nib
        </textarea>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You aren't removing this code anywhere. `$('textarea').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).val();
            $(this).after('<p class="well print-content">' + text + '</p>');
        });` But still, based on your CSS, it should not display. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `media="print"` from your style tag.

Comment: And you are the most eloquent, well-explained gun in the west :^)

Comment: !@Darren !

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the problem is with the way you have added your style tag. You have set an attribute `media="print"`, so the following CSS **will not** get applied on screen.

```css
.print-content {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The solution is to remove the `media="print"` as you have already added `@media print {}` using `@media` queries.